How to deploy docker-compose application in App service deployment slot using Azure Devops
I have setup a CICD pipeline to deploy my multi-container docker-compose app on azure app service.
My current workflow goes like this:
I have multiple build pipelines for each container.
Each build pipeline does the following steps:
1. Uses 'Docker@2' task to build docker image and push it to Azure Container Registry.
2. Updates the variables in variable group to update the 'tag' for docker image.

After the build pipeline, the release pipeline does following tasks:
1. Downloads the 'docker-compose.template.yml' file from artifact.
2. Replace the ${TAG} parameters in 'docker-compose.template.yml' file with the updated tag from variable group.
3. Deploys the updated docker-compose.yml to Azure App Service.

The above workflow works fine (Please review this workflow as I am new to this and not sure if this is the best way to deploy multiple container app in app service using azure devops).
Now I want to use deployment slots (stg and production).
I tried 'Azure App Service manage' task to swap slots in my App Service but it didn't work. The deployment center (prod slot) is not using Azure devops as deployment source. I understand that deployment center is isolated to the specific slot.
I guess it will work if I use docker-compose.yml file or config in deployment center (I haven't tested it yet). But we need to use Azure devops.
Can anyone please let me know if Azure supports deployment slot for docker-compose application deployment from azure devops?
If not, is there any other alternative to ensure zero downtime while deploying to production slot?

As per this Doc , yes you can use Deployment slots from Azure Devops.
